# Can a user access files if he does not have access to the parent directory?

Tags: permissions, directory

If I have a folder with e.g. the following permissions (0700):

```
drwx------  2 patrick patrick   4096 Sep 12 00:00 test
```

If I understand it correctly, this means only the folders owner can:

- read: list files
- write: create, delete and rename files (but this only works if execute is set as well)
- execute: access file contents and meta-information

If I now add a file to the folder with the permission (0777):

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 patrick patrick    0 Sep 12 00:00 testfile
```

There is no way another user can access the file, even as the file itself can be read, written and executed by all users. Am I correct or am missing some finer points of the Unix permission system?

If I'm correct, is there any reason (except keeping things nice and tidy) to still worry about correct file permissions in that folder? Are there cases (e.g. accesses via relative paths?) where other users may still access the said file?

Comment: "execute" access on dirs hasn't anything to do with "accessing filie contents and meta-info" (that is controlled by the file's _own_ permissions). "execute" access on a directory means "search" access: `x` permission on `dir` gives you permission to access `dir/file`, which is independent of whether you're able to _list_ the content of `dir` or not (for which you need the `r` permission).

Comment: So just to ensure I got it right: If an user e.g. only has `--x` access to a folder, he can access the content of the all the files in that folder? Isn't "search" not just another term for read, as to search you need to read the file.

Comment: No, search (`x`) is not another term for read (`r`). Being able to read the content of a directory (ie `ls` it) doesn't mean you're able to access its files. Just try it: `mkdir dir; echo yup > dir/yup; chmod 400 dir; ls dir; cat dir/yup`

Comment: And being able to access its files doesn't mean you're able to list them: `mkdir dir1; echo yup > dir1/yup; chmod 100 dir1; ls dir1; cat dir1/yup`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I got that. My point was: Giving a user `x` permission on a directory gives read permission for **the files in that directory** so they can be searched, correct?

Comment: Any permission on a directory doesn't have anything to do with the permission on its files. On linux, a directory is _not_ a folder: it only contains "pointers" to the actual files -- the files "contained" within it can be also accessed via another directory.

Comment: Giving `x` on the directory allows the user to enter and traverse the directory. What they can do with the file inside depends on the permissions of the file itself. They can run `ls` directly against the file or read the contents with `cat` or a text editor as I've explained in my answer.

Comment: @mosvy thanks for the effort, now I've got it. Nasir Riley's answer let me wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file could be hard-linked elsewhere (and on Linux, bind-mounted elsewhere), and that will bypass the permissions of the containing original directory:

```
# mkdir dir; echo yup > dir/in
# ln dir/in out
# touch out-b; mount --bind dir/in out-b
# chmod 700 dir
# su user

user$ cat out out-b
yup
yup
user$ cat dir/in
cat: dir/in: Permission denied
user$ ls dir/in
ls: cannot access 'dir/in': Permission denied
user$ ls dir
ls: cannot open directory 'dir': Permission denied
```

As such a hard-link or bind-mount can happen inadvertently (as part of something else, etc) it's **never** a good idea to give more permissions than necessary.

> `drwx------  2 patrick patrick   4096 Sep 12 00:00 test`
>
> If I understand it correctly, this means only the folders owner can:
>
> execute: access file contents and meta-information

No, the `x` (execute/search) permission on a directory doesn't mean that. It means that only the owner can access the files via the entries of this directory. Acessing the files' contents is controlled by their *own* permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The `r` means that you can read the directory or the file itself. The `x` on a directory means that it can be traversed.

With the way that you have the permission set in your question, users and groups other than patrick can't enter the directory or list its contents. They can run `ls` directly on the contents of the directory but it will just return `permission denied` instead of giving any info.

If you give `x` permissions on the directory and nothing else then they can `cd` into the directory. If they run `ls` inside of the directory then it will give them `permission denied` but if they know or can guess the name of files inside then they can run `ls` directly on them and see that they exist. They can also read the contents of the file(s) with `cat` or `vim` or another text editor if they have read permissions on it.

If you give `r` permissions on the directory and nothing else then the user can't `cd` into the directory but they can run `ls` on it and see its contents although they can't run `ls` against the file(s) itself or use `cat` or `vim` to see the contents.

Comment: Thanks @Nasir Riley, that let me wrap my head around it! Even though I've accepted mosvy's answer, as it answers they original question, this really helped. Maybe it would be beset to add your comment to the other answer?

Comment: "x on a directory means that it can be traversed" was key for me. Root/containing directory permissions dictate the maximum possible access to contained files (e.g. if o-x on a dir, then in general o does not have access to contained files).